# Silverstripe DataObject - drag and drop ordering

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverstripe

Silverstripe DataObject - I want to add drag and drop ordering to a current Class that extends dataobject like what exists for pages. So when dropped it updates an OrderBy field for all the dataobjects in that view. I created the class and can freely edit one item at a time, but a simple drag and drop ordering would make it so much easier but I can not see any such extensions currently on Dataobjects only on Pages.

Answer (score 6):

In SilverStripe 3.1 there are a few excellent modules that give you this sort of functionality. Two of these modules are [SortableGridField](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField) and [GridFieldExtensions](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions).

To get this working you need to install one of these modules, add a sort field to your custom `DataObject` class and add the module sort object component to your `GridFieldConfig`.

### [SortableGridField](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField)

The [`SortableGridField`](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField/blob/master/docs/HasManyExample.md#has_many-example) module is specifically to allow sorting functionality for objects on a `GridField`.

To get this working you need to add a sort field to your custom `DataObject` class and add `GridFieldSortableRows()` as a component to your `GridField`.

For the following examples I will use `HomePage` as the page with a has_many relationship to a `Slide` DataObject.

#### Slide

```php
class Slide extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array (
        'Title' => 'HTMLText',
        'SortOrder' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array (
        'HomePage' => 'HomePage'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array( 
        'Title' => 'Title'
    );

    private static $default_sort = 'SortOrder ASC';
    private static $singular_name = 'Slide';
    private static $plural_name = 'Slides';

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->removeByName('SortOrder');

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

#### HomePage

```php
class HomePage extends Page {

    private static $has_many = array (
        'Slides' => 'Slide'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $slidesFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
        $slidesFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));

        $slidesField = GridField::create(
            'Slides',
            'Slide',
            $this->Slides(),
            $slidesFieldConfig
        ); 
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', $slidesField);

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

### [GridFieldExtensions](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions)

The `GridFieldExtensions` module contains [`GridFieldOrderableRows`](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/blob/master/docs/en/index.md#orderable-rows) to control the sort order on a GridField, just like the `SortableGridField` module. It also has other useful `GridField` tools.

To get this working you need to add a sort field to your custom `DataObject` class and add `GridFieldOrderableRows()` as a component to your `GridField`.

Your code would be just like the above example except the component you add to your `GridFieldConfig` is `GridFieldOrderableRows`:

```php
    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $slidesFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
        $slidesFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('SortOrder'));

        ...
    }
```

Comment: you beat me to it 3dgoo! Sortable GridField module is indeed what you'd be after :)