# SS3 DataObject sort after specified DataObject

Tags: silverstripe

Ok, so this has been driving me crazy for the past couple days...
I have a DataObject like so:

```
private static $db = array(
    // other properties
    'active' => 'Boolean',
    'sort' => 'Int' // ID of another DataObject of this type, after which it is to be displayed.
);
private static $has_one = array('Page' => 'CustomPage');
```

The CustomPage just extends Page and has a has_many relationship with this DataObject.
The pain now for me is to get the data in a way that they're correctly sorted.

**EDIT:** The sort value is actually the ID of the DataObject after which to sort this one.

For example given the following:

```
ID    sort
1      0
2      3
3      5
4      1
5      1
```

The result should be ordered like this:

```
ID
1
4
5
3
2
```

The sort can be duplicated, since I don't really want to bother with updating every item whenever I just add something in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

One way to set the sort order of a `DataObject` is to set the `$default_sort` variable:

```
class CustomDataObject extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Active' => 'Boolean',
        'SortOrder' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'CustomPage'
    );

    private static $default_sort = 'SortOrder ASC';
}
```

Make sure you call `?flush=all` after doing this to clear the site cache.

Also, if the custom `DataObject` is being maintained through a `GridField` we can use module to control the sort order through drag and drop. Here is a StackOverflow answer detailing how to use one of these modules:
[Silverstripe DataObject - drag and drop ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844929/silverstripe-dataobject-drag-and-drop-ordering/28845421#28845421)

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that the sort value is actually the ID of the DataObject after which to sort this one. So I can't just order by sort, as that'll not correctly sort. For example it would put 2 before 3 when it actually is supposed to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As 3dgoo stated `$default_sort`is your friend. When your column `sort` (or `SortOrder`) isn't unique you can always add another column to sort duplicates, so something like

```
private static $default_sort = 'sort, ID ASC';
```

should work in your case.